# Do we need to produce video assets in iOS apps at @3x @2x and @1x as for image assets?

Tags: ios, video, screen

I understand the requirement for images but do apps have to respect the same variations for embedded videos? If not what resolution should be used?

Comment: Most likely not, but anyway you shouldn't store videos in your app (they take up way too much space)

Answer (score 0):

No, no need this action. You can use any resolution to your project. App size will be increased by video size.

But if you use this video in AppStore preview. You should use different size videos. You can look [app-previews](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/)